# pdfx and "undefined control sequence" caused by Subject meta-tag

Tags: pdftex, pdf

According to the [pdfx documentation](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=pdfx.pdf&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CFcQFjAB&url=http://mirror.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/pub/mirrors/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfx/pdfx.pdf&ei=7XkIUNjdKJDVsgaMmsWWAw&usg=AFQjCNGDTQGfrysl76WVTBGH1-dLNBRUeg) it should be possible to add a Subject field to the XMP metadata file. Addition of this field however seems to cause an unexpected error during compilation of the LaTeX source into a PDF/A-1b file (pdfLaTex).

Try to compile the following source:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\begin{document}
Hello, World!
\end{document}
```

using this metadata:

```
\Author{Me}
\Title{Hello, World!}
\Subject{Hello, World! example.}
\Org{Me}
\Keywords{Hello\sep World}
```

The source compiles without errors after omission of the Subject tag.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** I found a solution with two patches.

First patch (`pdfx.sty`):

```
52c52,53
<  \let\xmpSubject\xmpKeywords
---
> \def\Subject#1{\gdef\xmpSubject{#1}}
>  \let\xmpSubject\@empty
```

Second patch (`pdfa-1b.xmp`):

```
34a35,37
>    <dc:description>
>      <rdf:Alt><rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">\xmpSubject</rdf:li></rdf:Alt>
>    </dc:description>
```

With this two patches, all is fine (for *Subject*).

Comment: You may be right, see the following link: http://www.pdfa.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/tn0003_metadata_in_pdfa-1_2008-03-182.pdf

Answer (score 2):

This look like a bug in `pdfx`: `\Subject` is documented, but I can find no implementation. Please report it to the authors.